# Как сравнить значения из DataGridViev со значением в Textbox и выделить наиболее подходящее цветом в таблице C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужна помощь с программированием на C#
Может ли кто то подсказать код(способ,действие),который анализирует значения в DataGridViev,вычитая значения в таблице из заданного значения и выбирая наименьшее по модулю,чтобы в итоге это значение выделялось в таблице либо цветом либо еще как нибудь
Вот код моей программы:

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!CheckInput_Int(textBox2) ||
            !CheckInput_Double(textBox8) ||
            !CheckInput_Double(textBox9) ||
            !CheckInput_Double(textBox10) ||
            !CheckInput_Double(textBox11) ||
            !CheckInput_Double(textBox6) ||
            !CheckInput_Double(textBox7))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Проверьте значения полей!", "Внимание!",
              MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

        int gg = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        dataGridView1.RowCount = gg;

        double
                t_kond = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text), t_dear = Convert.ToDouble(textBox9.Text),
                t_oe = Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text), t_egu = Convert.ToDouble(textBox11.Text),
                z = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text), alfa = 0.9, tp_pereddear = t_dear - 10,
                t_nach = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text), p_pg = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text),

              t_pv = ((t_nach - t_kond - t_oe - t_egu) / (z + 1)),
              t_pvopt = t_nach - t_pv,
              t_pvek = alfa * (t_pvopt - t_kond) + t_kond;

        double yBase = t_kond + t_oe + t_egu + t_pv;
        double[] x = new double[gg];
        double[] y = new double[gg];

        for (int i = 0; i < gg; i++)
        {
            x[i] = i + 1;
            y[i] = yBase + t_pv * i;


            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = x[i].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = y[i].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ColorCellWithClosestValue(double aValue, Color aColor)
{
  // coordinates of cell with closest value
  int col = -1; 
  int row = -1;
  // current minimal difference 
  double delta = 0;
  // current cell value
  double value;
  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
    {
      if (double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value), out value))
      {
        if (Math.Abs(aValue - value) < delta)
        {
          delta = Math.Abs(aValue - value);
          row = i;
          col = j;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (row >= 0 && col >= 0)
    dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Style.ForeColor = aColor;
}

private void btnCompareClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // call it like this:
  double value;
  if (double.TryParse(textboxCompare.Text, out value))
  {
    ColorCellWithClosestValue(value, Color.Red);
  }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54395/discussion-on-answer-by-igor-----datagridviev--).